# PHP FizzBuzz Logic

Tags: php, logical-operators, fizzbuzz

When we write the fizzbuzz script, why are we testing to see if it is equal to 0? Or am I misunderstanding?

Example: $i % 3 == 0

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    if ($i%3==0 && $i%5==0) {
        echo 'FizzBuzz';
    }else if($i%3==0){
        echo 'Fizz';
    }else if($i%5==0){
        echo 'Buzz';
    }else{
        echo $i;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: 'n divisible by x' => 'n % x === 0'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program fizzbuzz prints 'fizz' if a number is divisible by 3, 'buzz' if a number is divisible by 5, and 'fizzbuzz' if a number is divisible by both.

Your program is not checking if the numbers are equal to 0, instead it is using the `modulo` operator to check if the **remainders** are 0.

`$i%3==0` means number is divisible by 3

`$i%5==0` means number is divisible by 5

`$i%5==0 && $i%3==0` means the number is divisible by both

Comment: This was very helpful. I understand now exactly. Thanks for educating me!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
array_map(function($l) {
  echo $l . PHP_EOL;
}, array_map(function($i) {
  $is_fizz = ($i % 3) === 0;
  $is_buzz = ($i % 5) === 0;
  return (!$is_fizz && !$is_buzz) ? $i : 
    ($is_fizz ? 'Fizz' : '') . ($is_buzz ? 'Buzz' : '');
}, range(1 , 100)));
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

A more concise but harder to read solution:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) { 
    print ( (fmod(($i/3),1)  ?  '' : "fizz") . (fmod(($i/5),1)  ?  '' : "buzz")  ?:  ("$i") ) ."\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Always include code description and make sure it's well-formatted.